# Seeing if a workbook contains data from another, and then adding the data if it doesn't?

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

Basically what title says, I have two separate workbooks with thousands of entries. One is an updated version of the other. I'm trying to find what's new in one workbook and add it to the older one.

Comment: Is there just one column of data or several? How would you, as human, tell if a line was new? Does every column have to be identical to count as a duplicate? Is there a single column with a unique ID we can check instead?

Comment: There's two columns per entry. As a human, if the first line was not present, then that would mean that the second line would not be either, since they correspond with each other. However, there are some entries where the first line would be the same, yet have a different corresponding second line

Comment: How about adding all data to the same Workbook and remove duplicate values? You can use Power Query, but I suggest you provide more information about your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, your data has two columns and you want to consider both when determining if a row is unique. First, let's add a helper column. For instance, if your data is in `A:B` with headers in the first row, you can use this formula in `C2`:

```
=A2&"|"&B2
```

I used a pipe `|` as a delimter just because it's rarely within normal text. If your values may contain a pipe, then pick some other character for that formula. Copy that formula down for the entire length of your data.

Add that helper column in both sheets. Now you have a column with a unique ID. The next step is to find the items in the new workbook aren't in the old one. For this, I like to use the [MATCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) function. Since your data is in two different workbooks, it is important to have both files open at the same time. (Your exact file and sheet names will be different than what is shown in this example but you can click on the range while writing the formula and Excel will fill in the reference for you.) The formula in the new workbook, cell `D2`, will look something like this:

```
=MATCH(C2,'[Old Workbook Name.xlsx]Sheet Name'!$C:$C,0)
```

This will return a row number if it finds a match and the error `#N/A` if it can't find a match. Again, copy it down for the length of your data. If you sort or filter to find all the rows with `#N/A`, then there's your list of items that appear in the new workbook but don't appear in the old file.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a go at using [Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_multisheetexcel) to do it.

(That is a link to the bit about comparing Excel files.)

I use Beyond Compare for any file comparisons. Being a software developer, I tend to need file diffs all the time and this is a great tool. (I have no afilliation with Scooter Software, I'm just a big fan of Beyond Compare! And you get a free 30-day trial last time I looked.)

As well as showing a side-by-side comparison of your two files, the tool allows you to edit the file(s) at the same time as viewing the diff, and to click to copy matching/non-matching lines from one file to the other.

And here's the thing: it doesn't just work with text files, it recognizes various common proprietary file formats too. Excel is one of them, and you can see at the link above how Beyond Compare will enable the same kind of editing with Excel files as it does with text files, so that you can align the two files left and right, see the differences, and copy over lines/blocks of your choice.